# How to clear filter breadcrumbs when grouped?

Tags: website-design, search, filter, search-results, breadcrumbs

I am implementing search filter breadcrumbs. From what I've seen on other sites, a single filter gets its own breadcrumb which can be cleared by pressing an 'x'.

**example**

[image: filter breadcrumbs - example one]

I want the user to be able to do this *and also* be able to clear an entire category from the breadcrumbs.

I have searched quite a bit and haven't found many examples of this. The way I visualise it at the moment is like this:

[image]

Another way might look like this:

[image]

I'm concerned that both methods might clutter up the interface, especially in an area where other important actions are placed. I'm also not sure that either method is the best way of implementing this feature.

Any feedback/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: isnt having 'clear all' both in the side bar and the main content redundant? i'd recommend not having clear in the main content,rather just allowing the user to clear their filter selection from the side panels. The main content breadcrumbs may be used to include or exclude selected filters

Comment: The sidebar has a lot of categories, so being able to clear all from the top could be a useful way to avoid scrolling, and to get a summary of what's been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the approach is about **enabling the user to clear the search results faster** . i'd recommend going with a *Clear x* call to action next to the breadcrumbs.

But is it really necessary to give multiple 'clear all's in the breadcrumb list.? If there are multiple categories of filters , we can just differentiate the categories in the breadcrumb bar with some subtle color differences and have a **single *clear all*** for the breadcrumbs.

Just my two cents :)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8u5hg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for you input! I hadn't thought of colour coding like that. There are about 8 categories, so maybe it could look a bit busy if they all had unique colours? Thanks again

Comment: True, but the trade off is -  different clustered colors or having 8 individual rows with filter breadcrumbs shown, in a worst case scenario . :)

Comment: You don't even need to color code it. From my experience, users don't need the pills to be categorized.

Comment: @Majo0od Thanks for input. I don't think I will use categories, it's very difficult to make it work.